# C# How to end an infinite loop that also recieves user input with the press of Escape in Console Application

Tags: c#, console, console-application, user-input, infinite-loop

I have just started learning C# and I'm practicing some basic coding in the console application and I'm trying to make a program that adds two integers together by using an infinite loop and a method. But I want to be able to end the loop by pressing escape but the problem is, is when I press any key besides escape after the loop has completed for the first time, the program crashes. It says "Input string was not in a correct format." Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Addxy(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x+y);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
            {
            Addxy(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

            ConsoleKeyInfo end;
            end = Console.ReadKey();

            if (end.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                break;
            else
            {

            }



            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use debuger to see the contents of string? You will see the reason... (if string is empty check its length)

Answer (score 0):

You have two `Console.ReadLine()` before `Console.ReadKey()`. So the first two inputs should be numerals followed by the Escape key to terminate the program. Remember to press Enter after the first two numeral entry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `break` to end the loop, but a more elegant way would be to define a variable that determines if the loop should keep running. Here is my suggestion for your problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool keepLooping = true;
    while (keepLooping)
    {
        //Do your stuff here
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            keepLooping = false;
        }
    }
}
```

or an even shorter version if you prefer that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool keepLooping = true;
    while (keepLooping)
    {
        //Do your stuff here
        keepLooping = Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape;
    }
}
```